# How to fix Developer Console testing failure, without reference to the own code?

Tags: android, developer-console

The Google Play Developer Console shows me the following Pre-Launch-Report, for the Galaxy S6, after uploading the APK. The other nine devices, which Google uses to test the APK, have no error.

The provided stacktrace shows none of my code lines. How can I figure out, whether this is a real problem, and how can I fix it, if it is not based on my code?

Developer Console output:

```
Problem: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String android.accounts.Account.type' on a null object reference

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.google.android.videos, PID: 28537
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String android.accounts.Account.type' on a null object reference
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
    at com.android.vending.contentfilters.IContentFiltersService$Stub$Proxy.getContentFiltersAndIntent(SourceFile:139)
    at com.google.android.videos.contentfiltering.ContentFiltersManager.saveContentFiltersToPreference(SourceFile:438)
    at com.google.android.videos.contentfiltering.ContentFiltersManager.access$100(SourceFile:81)
    at com.google.android.videos.contentfiltering.ContentFiltersManager$1.onServiceConnected(SourceFile:423)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1314)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1331)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Is this normal? Why do I get this error only for the Galaxy S6?

Comment: Did you ever work this out? It looks to me like the s6 they have their isn't set  up to record videos or something like that...

Comment: Same problem. I get this:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.google.android.videos, PID: 30330
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String android.accounts.Account.type' on a null object reference
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
(... very long trace ...) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199).


--- That is not part of my game.